# Chrome is not letting HTTP hosted site to access Camera & Microphone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, browser, webcam

I'm using [react-webcam](https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam) to capture a selfie for an application. On localhost, react-webcam works perfectly whereas on HTTP hosted web server camera access is being denied by default on the Chrome. Is there any workaround for webcam access or any other npm plugin which can serve the purpose here.

NOTE: HTTPS supported sites are allowed to access both the Camera & Microphone. Here, I'm left with only HTTP choice.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using this for a development environment and want to test it on your phone you can do the following:

- Go to: chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
- Enable `Insecure origins treated as secure`
- Add the addresses for which you want to ignore this policy
- Restart chrome

Comment: Took forever to find this, By default, localhost is https, but if you are testing something like socket.io or a technology on two devices this is essential if you don't want to set up ssl

Comment: This is not available any more on chrome app for ios

Answer (score 4):

The react-webcam uses the `getUserMedia` API which [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#x10.-obtaining-local-multimedia-content) states:

> When on an insecure origin [mixed-content], User Agents are encouraged to warn about usage of navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, navigator.getUserMedia, and any prefixed variants in their developer tools, error logs, etc. **It is explicitly permitted for User Agents to remove these APIs entirely when on an insecure origin**, as long as they remove all of them at once (e.g., they should not leave just the prefixed version available on insecure origins).

Chrome, starting from version 47 implements this security policy ([Source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en#public_service_announcements)):

> Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.

So you can't access Microphone or Camera without a secure connection.